# https://www.example.com not secure but https://example.com is secure?

Tags: asp.net

I have SSL for example.com (not my real site domain name) and https://example.com is protected.  When a user enters https://www.example.com the browser reports it as not secure.  How do I fix this?  This is what I have in my web.config file.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

You clearly get a wrong certificate. This certificate does not have CN or SAN for www.example.com, while most site certificates should have CN or SAN for both.

Either you contact your CA to issue you a new one or you add another rule in IIS URL Rewrite to redirect all access from www to root.

Comment: how do I write another rule, haven't found anything on the internet to do that.

Comment: Put this at top and let it stop processing after redirection, https://medium.com/iis-and-windows-server/redirect-url-from-www-to-non-www-in-iis7-5-4d2909b9704